# How can I use a scanned variable (Barcode) in an SQL query

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to use a scanned barcode as a variable in a SQL query. I am using the Google ML Kit [Quick Start](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) project. I have a connection and query function made using jtds1.3.1. I just cant get the raw value to be used in the query.

How could I call the query function with the raw value once the barcode has been scanned? 
How could I store the raw value in a variable each time a barcode is scanned?

```
override fun onSuccess(
        originalCameraImage: Bitmap?,
        barcodes: List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>,
        frameMetadata: FrameMetadata,
        graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay
    ) {
        graphicOverlay.clear()

        originalCameraImage?.let {
            val imageGraphic = CameraImageGraphic(graphicOverlay, it)
            graphicOverlay.add(imageGraphic)
        }

        barcodes.forEach {
            val barcodeGraphic = BarcodeGraphic(graphicOverlay, it)
            graphicOverlay.add(barcodeGraphic)
        }
        graphicOverlay.postInvalidate()
    }
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted over 300 lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for the insight! I have cleaned up the question significantly. Hopefully this is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something along these lines:

```
override fun onSuccess(
        originalCameraImage: Bitmap?,
        barcodes: List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>,
        frameMetadata: FrameMetadata,
        graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay) {

    String barcodeValue = barcodes.get(0).getRawValue();

    PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement("insert into scanned_barcodes(barcode) values (?)");
    stmt.setString(1, barcodeValue);
    stmt.execute();
}
```

The scanned barcodes are in the `barcodes` list. The value can be accessed with `getRawValue()`.

The rest of the code is regular JDBC code: create a statement, bind the current value and execute it.

Comment: Thank you @Codo This was exactly what I needed!